# Code Won't Ask User for Input?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python programming. Using Python3 for class.

The code I have is:

```
#!/usr/binpython3
import arduino
def loop():
      contin = True
      while contin:
             userinput = input()
             if userinput == "quit":
                      contin = False
             else:
                      contin = True
```

I am stuck at the "userinput = input()" portion of my code. For some reason, my program would not ask user for the input. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: `#!/usr/binpython3` shoud be `#!/usr/bin/python3`. and do you ever call the function `loop()`?

Comment: I'm so dumb. Was looking at so many examples of these and completely forgot about calling the function back again. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you actually calling the function? That is, are you saying `loop()` at the end of your code?

Comment: Ughh, that is exactly what I forgot. Didn't realize I had to call it back afterwards, since it was only being defined. Thank you very much.